# Boto3 upload to S3: cut off last few rows of data from a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

When I upload a .csv file using boto3 (Python), the last few rows of data get cut off. The size of the file is 268KB which should not to be too big for non-multipart upload. Here is my code:

```
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.client('s3') 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(report_file.name, 'raw-data-bucket', 'Reports/report.csv')
```

*These are not exact bucket and path I've used but they suould be irrelevant in this case 
Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you closed the file you are uploading to S3 before using .upload_file() ?  I had the exact same problem with my *.CSV file upoads, and solved it by explicitly closing each file before uploading it, and the problem was solved.  No more truncated *.CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I was performing the upload before closing my filehandle. As someone else suggested closing the file first and then uploading fixed the issue.

This caused the uploaded file to be missing the last chunk.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("s3")
data = {...}
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
    client.upload_file("file.json", "my-bucket", "some/prefix/file.json")
```

This resolved my issue:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("s3")
data = {...}
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
client.upload_file("file.json", "my-bucket", "some/prefix/file.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this person had the same issue

[256kb stackoverflow similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678578/image-file-cut-off-when-uploading-to-aws-s3-bucket-via-django-and-boto3)

Also, they provide the multi uplaod part in boto3 [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#multipartupload)

Comment: I read this and I tried it before asking my question but it did not really help me. I should not need multipart upload for files of that size. Also I am not really sure how to check if my file gets base64 encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with one service(either resource or client).

```
# Using boto3 service client
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.client('s3') 
s3.upload_file('your_local_file_path", 'bucket_name', 'prefix_filename_to_s3')
```

For service resource

```
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('bucket_name', 'you_local_file_path').upload_file('prefix_filename_to_s3')
```

Check again the content of your "report_file.name". S3.upload_file works as GIGO(garbage in garbage out), it doesn't truncate data.

(update)
After a further check, [there is another case](https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/816) that I am not sure whether they are related. There is suggest that the httppretty module boto3 use is not thread safe, you should update your boto3 version and disable the thread.

```
 from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig
    config = TransferConfig(use_threads=False)
    client.download_file(Bucket="mybucket",
      Key="foo/bar.fastq.gz", Filename="bar.fastq.gz", Config=config)
```

Comment: I just tried both ways and i am still missing the last 30 rows of data. When I download the data locally it is all fine. I tried also to download and upload as diffrent formats (CSV, XLSX, TSV) and the data was still cut when uploaded to s3. If I manually upload it to s3, the data is fine. What could be the reason for losing the data when uploaded with boto3?

Comment: @Inna  What is your boto3 version? i.e. `pip freeze | grep "boto3"`

Comment: The version I have when I run the code through my terminal is
boto3==1.4.4
botocore==1.5.65

I also run into the same problem when I run my scripts through my cluster which has 
boto==2.39.0
botocore==1.4.46

Comment: @Inna please try the updated suggestion.   Try record down the behavior to confirm the real culprits, e.g.  i. upload using boto3 , download with AWS CLI, compare file  ii. upload using AWS CLI , download with boto3, compare file

Comment: I just tried uploading using tinys3 and the last 30 lines are still missing. So the problem is not really in boto3 and I guess I have the same problem as [256kb stackoverflow similar problem] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678578/image-file-cut-off-when-uploading-to-aws-s3-bucket-via-django-and-boto3). I do not really know much about base64 encoding and decoding so I am not quite sure how to test this.

Comment: @inna "truncated" data can happen either i. During upload, ii. During download.  That's why I ask you to try using different upload/download method to check which side is the real culprits. 
If you are not sure, diagnose using this AWS documentation. 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/

Comment: Problem solved! I had open the file before uploading it and closed it after the upload. I just moved the closing line before the upload and it worked! Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: @Inna  `s3.client.upload_file` works directly under file level, you don't need to open the file actually. OTH, `s3.client.upload_fileobj` is another story.